# Almost invariant vs invariant in the strict sense.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I am currently studying Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples.

I have question with this excercise.

> $A$ is almost invariant if $P(A\Delta \varphi^{-1}(A))=0$ and call $C$ invariant in the strict sense if $C=\varphi^{-1}C$. Let $A$ be any set.
> Prove $A$ is almost invariant if and only if there is a $C$ invariant in the strict sense with $P(A\Delta C)=0$.

Proving the if part, in the solution, the following equality is used.
$$P(\varphi^{-1}(A)\Delta C) = P(\varphi^{-1}(A)\Delta \varphi^{-1}(C)) =P(\varphi^{-1} (A\Delta C))=P(A\Delta C)=0$$

However how does $P(\varphi^{-1}(A\Delta C))= P(A\Delta C)$ hold?

Doesn't the above equality hold when $\varphi^{-1}(A-C)=A-C$ which is not mentioned in the problem?

Comment: I'm assuming $\varphi$ is measure-preserving.